# Server scaled images within WP Canvas - Gallery.

Tags: wordpress, image, scaling, load-time

If this is the wrong outlet for my question, my sincere apologies. I'm trying to improve my load times, I'm using a masonry plugin (WP Canvas - Gallery) for my galleries. They currently use the full high res image even when in the grid. It makes my load times terrible. If there is a way to change that it'd be great! 
Also if anyone knows a way to use the lazy load within this system that would also be great! 
my site can be found [here](http://www.overlandparkphotographer.com/senior-photographer/).

Answer (score 0):

I did a Pingdom Website Speed Test and the load time was ok at 3 sec. I like Fancybox as a versatile tool with many functions and options. You can read more about it and see examples [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples). There is also a [Fancybox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) WordPress Plugin. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I use the WP Canvas because it allows me to display my images in a smaller view, but not constraining aspect ratios. I haven't found to many solutions that do that effectively.